# Hibernate attaching new object to session but not actually saving them

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I want to get following functionality , I am not sure if hibernate

```
 MyEntity e = new MyEntity("xxx"); 

 Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
 MyEntity e2 = new MyEntity2();
 e2.setName("This will be saved");
 session.beginTransaction();
 session.save(e); // Well I do not want to save but only want to attach to session
 e.setName("yyy"); 

// I want to Use object "e" in memory only.

 session.evict(e);
 session.getTransaction().commit();
 session.close();
```

Now as you can see I want some objects to save but not one particular object "e" in this case. I know this is possible for existing objects , but not sure if I can do this with newly created objects.

Comment: Just Checked the documentation on hibernate seems like persist is the answer().

Comment: What's the point in calling save(), persist() or any other method attaching the object to the session if you don't want this object to be persistent?

Comment: I want it to be persistent in memory , but not actually save it reason the legacy application that I have got does delete all those records in the end of large transaction. I know its odd , however as I said its a legacy application. Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: Persistent in memory doesn't mean anything. `new MyEntity()` constructs an object which is in memory. You don't need the Hibernate session to have objects in memory.

Comment: Yes that is that true , however in this legacy code I have seen that object being used in many places and loaded via hibernate. We can use threadlocal or something similar or without changing existing code use hibernate to provide us what we are looking for.